# Finding 2 least correlating/similar lists in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, computer-science

I have a list of paths taken from networkX by `nx.shortest_simple_paths(g,s,d)` and the paths are:

```
[[T1, E1B, E2B, ACD6B, DE6, T3],
 [T1, E1B, ACD3B, ACD6B, DE6, T3],
 [T1, E1B, ACD3B, DE2, DE4, DE6, T3],
 [T1, E1B, E2B, ACD6B, ACD3B, DE2, DE4, DE6, T3]]
```

What I am trying to do is to find two paths which are the least similar to each other, the `disjointpaths` in networkX does not always return two paths in my case and I need exactly two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nx.disjointpaths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.connectivity.disjoint_paths.edge_disjoint_paths.html#networkx-algorithms-connectivity-disjoint-paths-edge-disjoint-paths) finds paths that do not share any edge. While all of the paths in your input share edges, you can find the pairing of paths that have the fewest edges in common:

```
def edges(p):
   return {(p[i], p[i+1]) for i in range(len(p)-1)}

paths = [['T1', 'E1B', 'E2B', 'ACD6B', 'DE6', 'T3'], ['T1', 'E1B', 'ACD3B', 'ACD6B', 'DE6', 'T3'], ['T1', 'E1B', 'ACD3B', 'DE2', 'DE4', 'DE6', 'T3'], ['T1', 'E1B', 'E2B', 'ACD6B', 'ACD3B', 'DE2', 'DE4', 'DE6', 'T3']]
r = {(tuple(j), tuple(k)):edges(j)&edges(k) for j in paths for k in paths if j!=k}
s1, s2 = min(r, key=lambda x:len(r[x]))
print(s1, s2)
```

Output:

```
('T1', 'E1B', 'E2B', 'ACD6B', 'DE6', 'T3') 
('T1', 'E1B', 'ACD3B', 'DE2', 'DE4', 'DE6', 'T3')
```

Comment: Thank you!  I basically applied another brute force approach but your seems way better. 
(newbie here ) xD